# При запуске в командной строке все Unicode символы на python превращаются в ⍰

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, unicode

Пишу игру с использованием символов Unicode на python, но при запуске в командной строке все эти символы превращаются в ⍰, почему так происходит и как можно это исправить?

Comment: windows? запускаете в консоли cmd?

Comment: да, Windows 10 Home

Comment: в настройках консоли укажите кодировку

Comment: В смысле изменить шрифт?

Comment: запусти в консоли `chcp 65001`

Comment: Запустил, к сожалению все так же(